# Why does disk clone show a wrong new disk size?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, clone

In Ubuntu maverick, i cloned from a 6 GB USB drive to a 40 GB SSD drive. The USB drive was at 99% full at the time i did it.  everything ran fine and the new system boots up great. It occurs when I run :

```
df -ah
```

It shows my new drive sda2 as 6 gigs. When I run gparted it shows it at 37 gigs and 99% full.

When I run

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

it lists the size of /dev/sda as 37 GiB

I followed [these steps](http://shop.xtreamer.net/Support/questions/1103/How+to+copy+UltraOS+to+internal+HDD) to the letter and everything worked perfectly. Is there something else that i have to run to get the file system to realize that it only has 6 GB of data on it and not 37 GiB?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've created a 6GB partition on your 40GB disk, you should be able to use gparted to resize it.  Try checking doing

```
sudo df /dev/sda1
```

to confirm it.